# Rendering Collection View Cells inside Stackview

Tags: ios, swift, layout, uicollectionview, uistackview

I'm wondering how the `UICollectionView` will behave when we will embed it in `UIStackView` that is in the `UIScrollView`. As long as we will have to set `collectionView's` containerView `intrinsicContentSize` to be the `collectionView.contentSize.height` it will probably load all the data at the same time, so as we will add image fetching, shadows etc it will make it not super performant. Can we somehow avoid it? Of course it would be great to leave `UIStackView` as the collectionView is not the only embedded view in it :)

Main View

```
final class MainView: UIView {
    lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.isDirectionalLockEnabled = true
        return scrollView
    }()

    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        return stackView
    }()

   /// Adding subviews and setting constraints...
}
```

And here is the place where we embed our collectionView

```
final class ContainerView: UIView {

     var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
         let collectionView = UICollectionView()
         return collectionView
     }()

     override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: header.frame.width,
                          height: collectionView.frame.minY + 
    collectionView.contentSize.height)
    }

    /// Adding subviews and setting constraints...

}
```

This view is embeded in `MainViewController` `stackview`

Comment: Why would you need to embed the collection view in a stack view in the first place?

Comment: Maybe you could use lazy loading collection view? Take a look at: https://digitalleaves.com/blog/2016/02/flawless-uicollectionviews-and-uitableviews/ I would change the trigger when to load the data based on ```UIScrollView``` position

Comment: @AlanS I'm using approach where you embed `viewController.view` in `stackView` so you can reuse it and you can delegate view logic into separate places :) 

@NikolaRistic Ye... That could work :D